# How would a native speaker formulate this request?

Tags: conversation

We went to a pet hospital because my dog was scratching her ears and they looked infected. I got a pill for my dog to take every day. And it worked.

So we continued to give her the pills until gone. I then returned for more pills.

They were out so we got a creme instead. But we had paid for the pill first and that was more expensive than the creme we got so they told me that I would get the money back the next time I come. And I went to that hospital again and wanted to ask for the money back.

But as you can see above my English is very childish and informal.

How would you make such a request clearly, simply and formally?

Comment: The OP is requesting help with how to use English to make a request, not for proofreading.

Answer (score 4):

You could say:

The person who helped me here last time told me to come back and ask for a refund for some medication.

If you just say that, and wait, they will probably ask you some questions and try to find some information on your account.

If that didn't work, you could probably tell the whole story again, slowly and calmly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask them either to **refund** the amount you overpaid or to **credit** that amount towards your current bill.

You **overpaid** the last time you were in.  You had attempted to **refill a prescription** and had paid for it, but the pills you requested were **out of stock**; so they gave you instead a less expensive alternative, a topical ointment, and told you that they would make the necessary **adjustments** the next time you came in.